# Azure Devops Change the Deploy Folder

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops

I am using Azure Devops for automatic build & deploy of asp.net core 3.1 web app to Azure App Service.

The problem is that it's deploying the app to strange folder. Instead of the wwwroot folder it is in
 `/home/site/wwwroot/Content/D_C/a/1/s/ExampleFolder/ExampleFolder2/ExampleFolder3/obj/Staging/netcoreapp3.1/PubTmp/Out`
The app service is on Linux if it matters.

How I can just fix/change it to be in the main folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should share your Pipeline with us, otherwise, we can't tell you what you have to change/fix.

However, here an example that uses the [AzureWebApp@1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app?view=azure-devops) Task to deploy a .NET Core 3.1 application to an Azure Web App.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: 'BuildArtifact'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:

    - task: UseDotNet@2
      inputs:
        packageType: sdk
        version: 3.1.x

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        projects: PATH/TO/YOUR/Project.csproj
        arguments: --output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output --configuration Release

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: 'Deploy'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    environment: Development
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: Azure Web App Deploy
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: YourAzureSubscription
              appName: YourAppName
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
              appType: webAppLinux
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!
It is deploying successfully so I think the only problem is the path of the deployment? Can you tell me which is the configuration for that or it's not so straigthforward as I think? @martin-brandl

Comment: in the deployment you only specify the path to your package. So your error might be in the build process? How are you building your application=

Comment: https://pastebin.com/dc97WmVx
This is the Build Solution YAML. Tell me if you need anything else.

Comment: @AlexanderPetkov Why don't you use the .net core cli to builld the project? This will probably solve your issue.

Comment: In the Publish Artifact there is "Path to publish" setting. Do you think this is what I need to change? https://imgur.com/a/ZRIv7gM

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by creating new Pipeline which is using `dotnet` agents instead of Visual Studio build agents. When you are deploying to Linux App Service make sure to use CLI. You can see @martin-brandl answer for example pipeline.

You can also refer to this Devops SE question. The problem is similiar:
https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/9598/azure-devops-artifact-zip-folder-structure-for-net-core-3-0-application

> I'm looking this fact:
>
> > I have an ASP.NET Core 3.0 application for which I have a full CI/CD setup in Azure DevOps. The Application is hosted on a Ubuntu 18.04 server machine.
>
> Therefore I can safely assume that you are developing ASP.NET Core 3.0 app to be hosted in Ubuntu. Any .NET Core 3.0 (or later) application means that you should rely on the `dotnet build` instead of using VSBuild.
>
> Also you had stated that you will host the app on Ubuntu 18.x, then you should also run the build on Azure DevOps agent that runs on Ubuntu. This means you should only use `dotnet build` in `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task, because `VSBuild` task only runs on Windows based agent, not Ubuntu and it is intended to compile .NET Framework and other platform other than .NET Core.
>
> Please consult the official doc of DotNetCoreCLI@2 task at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops
>
> After you use `dotnet build`, use `dotnet publish` to publish your artifact. It is much easier and it's also the best way to publish .NET Core apps.
>
> I have sample usage of `dotnet build` and `dotnet publish` of this on my repo: https://github.com/eriawan/dotnetcore-cicd-samples/blob/master/yaml-samples/sample_pipelines_check.yml