# Deploying .net core 3.1 web app to Azure Linux App Service

Tags: linux, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, .net-core-3.1

I've set up the release in Azure Devops to deploy a .net core 3.1 app to a Linux App Service in Azure. This seems to push the code to Azure, but to a really weird path:

Index of `/wwwroot/Content/d_C/a/1/s/[MyProject]/obj/Release/netcoreapp3.1/PubTmp/Out/`

This contains all the dlls and then a wwwroot directory which has all the files & folders found in my web project.

Here is my [Release set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4Nhu.jpg). Anyone have any ideas why my release isn't publishing to /home/site/wwwroot/? Others have said that this is where the site should be published to. Is there something I need to set up in the Azure portal or is this a Devops thing?

Comment: May I know does below method is work for you? Dose it make you achieve the wanted path in azure? Free to comment below if you still has any puzzle:-)

Comment: I have the exact same issue. how did you solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

This wired path should not relevant with the configuration of Azure app service deploy task or Azure portal *(Just ensure the `Physical path` value in Azure portal is `site/wwwroot`)*.

I guess you were using `Visual studio build task` to build your project, right? Because I faced the similar path structure if I use `VSbuild` task to build my `.net core` app. If yes, what the others told you is correct. This is the default action if you are using `Visual studio build task` in Build pipeline.

Others have explained this in detail, also provided the corresponding solution. You can refer to this [#1](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/9598/azure-devops-artifact-zip-folder-structure-for-net-core-3-0-application) for explanation of this default action. And check this [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60164200/azure-devops-change-the-deploy-folder) for work around.

> Therefore I can safely assume that you are developing ASP.NET Core 3.0
>   app to be hosted in Ubuntu. Any .NET Core 3.0 (or later) application
>   means that you should rely on the `dotnet build` instead of using
>   VSBuild.
>
> Also you had stated that you will host the app on Ubuntu 18.x, then
>   you should also run the build on Azure DevOps agent that runs on
>   Ubuntu. This means you should only use `dotnet build` in
>   `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task, because `VSBuild` task only runs on Windows
>   based agent, not Ubuntu and it is intended to compile .NET Framework
>   and other platform other than .NET Core.

So, to achieve what you want, here you need using [dotnet build task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops) to build your `.net core 3.1` project.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: PATH/TO/YOUR/Project.csproj
    arguments: --output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output --configuration Release
```